# Using CVS transparently through an SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, openssh, tunnel, cvs

It seems a simple thing, but I am stuck.

On an Ubuntu machine, to ssh into a particular `REMOTE_HOST` machine, until now I could do

```
ssh REMOTE_HOST
```

as expected (keys are all setup fine). Now, I am forced to setup an ssh tunnel through a particular `BRIDGE_HOST` machine with

```
ssh -L 2222:REMOTE_HOST:22 BRIDGE_HOST -N -f
```

and then I can ssh to the REMOTE_HOST with

```
ssh -p 2222 localhost
```

This works perfectly fine although things are a little more complicated. Here are a few problems:

- `localhost` runs OpenSSH_7.2p2 so there is no -J / ProxyJump option, if that would help. I am not able to update OpenSSH, or at least I would prefer to avoid it.
- I *must* login on `REMOTE_HOST` with a *password* so I *need* to use `sshpass` (please do not tell me that I should not, I have no control on this). So the first `ssh` command above is not quite as shown but more complicated; yet, I think it adds nothing to show the more complex version. But this is a constraint I have and, I am afraid, prevents some cleaner solutions.
- There is no shell on `REMOTE_HOST` and as far as I can tell (or I understand) I am only allowed to setup tunnels.

Anyway, I can ssh into `REMOTE_HOST` with these two steps, but what I would like to do is to hide all this in `.ssh/config` to make this transparent (especially for CVS, see below). Something like this appears to be fine:

```
Host REMOTE_HOST
   Hostname localhost
   Port 2222
   ProxyCommand tcsh -c "ssh -L 2222:REMOTE_HOST:22 BRIDGE_HOST -N -f; nc %h %p"
```

If I now run

```
ssh REMOTE_HOST
```

I can ssh into `REMOTE_HOST` as if the tunnel did not exist. Great.

The final source of complication (and the question) is that I want to use this ssh connection also for CVS. Everything is certainly setup fine from the CVS side (e.g., it was working when I did not have to use `BRIDGE_HOST`). And if I now run

```
cvs up
```

in an appropriate directory, everything seems to work fine... but the `cvs` command, after doing its job properly, never terminates. I seem to understand that this is because the ssh creating the tunnel is still running at the end. I would be happy to kill it, but I cannot figure out how. Relatedly, note that if I omit `ProxyCommand` in `.ssh/config` and if the tunnel is setup manually before, all is perfectly fine and CVS runs smoothly (and terminates). I would forget `ProxyCommand` and set up `autossh` but I understand it does not work with `sshpass`. I could setup a cron job or some script that manually keeps the tunnel alive, but I think (or hope) that there must be a better way....

What is the correct, simplest, and cleanest way to achieve the result I desire? That is, simply use `cvs` as always despite the insertion of `BRIDGE_HOST` on which I have no control whatsoever?

Comment: I am thinking that the correct thing to do would be to close the tunnel once `nc` has run. But I have a problem and I do not understand what happens. Imagine for a moment that the tunnel is setup manually before running `cvs up` and I set `ProxyCommand sh -c ">&2 echo START ; /bin/nc %h %p ; >&2 echo STOP"`, CVS runs fine, "START" is sent to the console before CVS runs, **but** "STOP" never appears. If I run the same command in the shell with %h = localhost and %p = 2222, the behaviour is as expected and STOP appears once `nc` dies with a CTRL-D. Why?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> localhost runs OpenSSH_7.2p2 so there is no -J / ProxyJump option, if that would help. I am not able to update OpenSSH, or at least I would prefer to avoid it.

A near-equivalent to ProxyJump is:

```
Host REMOTE_HOST
    ProxyCommand "ssh -W %h:%p BRIDGE_HOST"
```

This is actually what ProxyJump does in the background. The only real difference between the two is that ProxyJump would automatically copy certain other options (e.g. verbose `-v` mode) to all connections involved.

If the bridge server allows creating tunnels using `-L` then it automatically allows `-W` (and `-D` as well), as they all use the same SSHv2 channel type; the server doesn't know the difference.

This *should* also work with sshpass as the command. Alternatively, to avoid having to retype the password multiple times, you could use connection multiplexing for the bridge host:

```
Host BRIDGE_HOST
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/S.%r@%h:%p
```

The first connection to BRIDGE_HOST will leave a process in background; alternatively, you can use `ssh -fNM BRIDGE_HOST` (with sshpass if you want) to start the background process, which future `ssh -w ... BRIDGE_HOST` will automatically use.

---

In your tcsh+nc example, the command would be better written as:

```
Host REMOTE_HOST
    ProxyCommand tcsh -c "ssh -L 2222:%h:%p BRIDGE_HOST -N -f; nc localhost 2222"
```

Comment: user1686, about the near equivalence to ProxyJump, I assume you mean `-W` instead of `-w` (the latter is even more obscure to me and it looks like I am not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72270772/what-does-ssh-w). I did try it as `ProxyCommand sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -W %h:%p BRIDGE_HOST -l BRIDGE_USER` and, although I am not sure to understand it exactly, I get `channel 0: open failed: connect failed: open failed --stdio forwarding failed -- ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. I am afraid that I have no clue of what this means....

Comment: Yeah, it was supposed to be uppercase `-W`. Try running the command separately from shell (replacing `%h:%p` with the exact same `REMOTE_HOST:22` as you had in your original `-L` value – minus the local port) and see if it connects you to an "SSH-2.0-..." greeting message.

Comment: Yeees! Fantastic! I think you may have got wrong the %h and %p as I believe your correction to my tsch+nc example is incorrect in a similar way: %h is `localhost` and $p is `2222`. But `ProxyCommand sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -W REMOTE_HOST:22 BRIDGE_HOST -l BRIDGE_USER` appears to work perfectly well.

Comment: No, I think that's because you're still adding `HostName localhost` and `Port 2222` parameters to your config... They were deliberately left out in the examples, the original hostname from the `ssh REMOTE_HOST` command should carry over to %h by default.

Comment: I must be dumb but should it not work also with `Host *.REMOTE_DOMAIN`  instead of `Host REMOTE_HOST`? Checking with `sh -c ">&2 echo [...]"`, the command issued appears exactly the same (as it should), but then it hangs if I use the `*`....

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not manage to understand how to kill the tunnel once CVS is done with it and since I cannot use `autossh` with `sshpass`, I decided to add a cron job.

I first created a small script putting together a bunch of recipes and ideas found around on the web. Here is the script:

```
myself=${BASH_SOURCE[0]}

for pid in $(pgrep -d " " $myself); do
    if [ $pid != $$ ]; then
        kill -9 $pid
    fi 
done

while true
do
    pkill -f "sshpass.*2222:"
    sshpass -p PASSWORD ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -L 2222:REMOTE_HOST:22 BRIDGE_HOST -l USER -N
    sleep 1
done
```

Essentially it kills any other copy of itself first, then kills existing tunnel(s) on the same port and brings the required tunnel up, repeating this forever anytime `ssh` dies. It is a sort of poor man version of `autossh`.

Together with this `.ssh/config` file

```
Host REMOTE_HOST
   Hostname localhost
   Port 2222
```

this makes `ssh` (and CVS) behave as if REMOTE_HOST were still directly accessible.

The script can be conveniently invoked through `cron`:

```
  @reboot                            /PATH/TO/THE/SCRIPT &
  30         4     *     *     *     /PATH/TO/THE/SCRIPT &
```

The daily restart at 4:30am is probably perfectly unnecessary, but somehow seems a safe thing to do, in case something goes wrong.